# pdfbox error - Colorspace can't be determined at this time, about to return NULL from unhandled branch

Tags: pdfbox

I am using the following code to get a list of jpegs attached to one of my objects "PrintDocument" wich references a "Document" which references a "Page" Object. The path is being combined from Document and Page. But this is not the Problem. When I use this code and run it in simple java on the jvm, the pdf is being built without any error...

```
    public File createPDFtoPrint(PrintDocument pdocument)
        throws IncompleteDocumentException, IOException, FSException {
    File tmp = null;
    if(validatePrintDocument(pdocument)){

        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        Iterator<Page> iterator = pdocument.getDocument().getPageList().iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Page page = iterator.next();
            PDPage pdpage = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
            document.addPage( pdpage );

            PDPageContentStream contentStream = null;
            try {
                contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, pdpage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String message = "Error while creating contentStream for Page" + page.getPageNumber();
                logger.error(message);
                logger.debug(e.toString());
            }
            PDJpeg ximage;
            try {
                File imgFile = new File(docDir+"/"+pdocument.getDocument().getName()+"/"+page.getPageNumber()+".jpg");
                System.out.println("*************** FILEPATH IS "+imgFile.getPath());
                ximage = new PDJpeg(document,new FileInputStream(imgFile));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                String message = "File not found for Document " + pdocument.getDocument().getName() + "! Try uploading the PDF for this product!";
                logger.error(message);
                throw new FileNotFoundException(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String message = "Error while reading input file for document " + pdocument.getDocument().getName();
                logger.error(message);
                throw new IOException(message);             }

            if(ximage.getWidth()>ximage.getHeight()){
                AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(pdpage.getMediaBox().getWidth(), 0, 0, pdpage.getMediaBox().getHeight(), pdpage.getMediaBox().getWidth(), 0);
                at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
                contentStream.drawXObject(ximage,at);
            }
            else{
                AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(pdpage.getMediaBox().getWidth(), 0, 0, pdpage.getMediaBox().getHeight(), 0, 0);
                contentStream.drawXObject(ximage,at);
            }

            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

            //Pixel per Point
            float ppp = page.getPpp();

            Iterator<Field> cbIterator = pdocument.getCheckBoxMap().keySet().iterator();

            while(cbIterator.hasNext()){
                Field field = cbIterator.next();
                if(pdocument.getCheckBoxMap().get(field)){
                    contentStream.beginText();
                    contentStream.setFont( font, 14 );
                    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(field.getPosx()/ppp, field.getPosy()/ppp );
                    contentStream.drawString("x");
                    contentStream.endText();
                }
            }
```

BUT, when I use this in a EJB within the Glassfish Container I get the following errors, and the pages are blank:

```
[2015-05-05T01:57:59.739+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1430783879739] [levelValue: 800] [[2015-05-05 01:57:59 DEBUG PDXObjectImage:398 - Colorspace can't be determined at this time, about to return NULL from unhandled branch. filter = COSName{DCTDecode}]]

[2015-05-05T01:57:59.740+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1430783879740] [levelValue: 800] [[2015-05-05 01:57:59 DEBUG PDXObjectImage:400 - Can happen e.g. when constructing PDJpeg from ImageStream]]
```

Does anybody have any clue, why this is happening and how this can be solved?

Regards

Comment: Could you upload a "good" and a "bad" PDF file somewhere? Btw the "error" message is a debug message and is harmless... at least that's what the developer (me!) thought, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2443 . So I wonder if there's a different cause that the PDF is blank.

Comment: Hi and thanks alot for your reply. To anybody else reading this, dont make stupid errors like NOT CLOSING THE CONTENSTREAM. Thats what I had mistaken. ContentStream#close

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was, that the PDFs I am generating seemed to be empty. All white. But the error mentioned in the topic has nothing to do with that. It seems that this is a kind of error nobody, that not really cares about the colorspace should care about. The error, why my Documents seemed empty was that I was not closing the ContentStream after finishing a page. So ContentStream#close solved the problem in my case.